# How to determine function signature of a callable object?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Is there a way in C++ to determine function signature of a callable object?

Consider following:

```
template< typename F >
void fun(F f)
{
    // ...
}
```

Lets assume that `fun` is called only with callable "things".

Inside of `fun` I want to know what is the signature of function `f`. That should work with function pointers, references, wrappers, lambdas, binds, function objects (providing they have only one `operator ()`) and so on. I'm limited with Visual Studio 2010 SP 1 but am interested in standard solutions even if not working on that compiler.

(A function signature is `Return_Type ([Arg1_Type [, Arg2_Type [, ... ] ] ])`; same as given to `std::function`/`boost::function`.)

A partial solution of knowing at least the return value of `f` is of some value to. (I have tried `std::result_of` but couldn't get it to work in any case I tried.)

Comment: Why? Are you just trying to create an `std::function` object or something more complex?

Comment: If a function object has two different overloads of `operator()`, how would you decide which overload is its "signature"?

Comment: @Dennis: I want `f` to return object depending on how many arguments and of which types `f` takes and its return type to.

Comment: @Mike: If type has more than one `operator ()` then its "signature" is ambiguous. One could only ask whether such object supports given signature.

Comment: Interesting question indeed. I gave it a stab and came up with this [code](http://ideone.com/g3QVt) - it certainly isn't clean, but it does its job fairly good and I assume you could extract whole function signature from it.

Comment: @Vitus: I'm unable to test that code since you used variadic templates which are not supported in VS 2010. Could you provide a versions without them (limit yourself to 0 or 1 argument). Or even better: test your code against result of `std::bind`/`boost::bind`.

Comment: @Vitus: Also your `call` function takes arguments. I'm not sure whether this is needed or just used as part of the example. But as you can see in the above code I have more difficult case. I have to figure out number and types of arguments (that is way I need the signature!).

Comment: @Adam Badura: The arguments of `call` were used just for the example. The main problem with `bind` objects is that their `operator()` is usually template/is overloaded (at least in boost and gcc's stdlib) - which means you can't get the signature of it (without knowing the arguments). Even if `bind` object provided some typedefs, you can't rely on it, because the type of it is unspecified by standard (for `boost::bind`, perhaps there's something useful in boost's internals).

Comment: @vitus your code is not available via that link anymore. If it is a solution to this question, could you post it as an answer? I imagine that C++11 is more widely accepted today.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

On C++0x compliant compilers, you can at least get the result type of `f()` by using `decltype(f())`. Visual C++ 2010 should support decltype, though I haven't checked it myself yet. As for getting the argument types, I'm not sure if there's a way that would work with function pointers.

### Edit

Boost.Function seems to have it figured out, at least on *some* compilers (it doesn't work on old versions of VC++ or Borland C++ for instance). It can wrap function pointers and extract arguments for them. The solution seems quite complex however, and it involves defining multiple templates with Boost.PP. If you feel like trying to re-implement everything you can certainly try that, but I think you can also just use a dummy Boost.Function wrapper to make things easier, e.g. `boost::function<decltype(f)>::second_argument_type` to get the second argument type.

Comment: This assumes `f` takes no arguments.

Comment: Yes. If f() takes arguments decltype won't help, I'm afraid.

Comment: Exactly. VS 2010 supports `decltype` but unless I know what are the arguments (if any) and could provide some (if needed) - and saddly that is not the case here - it will not help on its own.

Comment: `boost::function<decltype(f)>` (which in my case would be simply `boost::function<F>`) does not compile. Same result with `std::function`. `X::function` could do this detection somehow but I'm not that sure as it does not really have to I guess. But even if it does it is so easly reusable.

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't compile? If it has lambda I don't think I can test here (I don't have boost compiled for V2010 yet), but at least some other people can.

Comment: Full (yet short) CPP file is at http://pokazywarka.pl/r6u3t4/ (comments are not useful for placing code samples).

Comment: Ah, Lambda. Well, I'll see if I can check it somewhere. Doesn't it work for you with function pointers, though? That's supposed to be the raison d'être of Boost.Function.

Comment: @Boaz: Note also that this specific code I used at the link does not work with neither `std::function` nor `boost::function`. Also it does not work with function pointers and function objects too and not just lambdas. This is simply because `function` expects function signature as template argument rather than those other types.

Answer (score 3):

You may look at Boost Function Types:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/function_types/doc/html/boost_functiontypes/introduction.html

Comment: especially function decomposition: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/function_types/doc/html/boost_functiontypes/reference/decomposition.html

Comment: I tired that before asking but I failed to use it in any way. Could you provide an example of use in particular with lambdas? (So that `fun` `cout`s for example `f` return type and first argument type.)

Answer (score 3):

While trying to solve this I came up with following partial solution:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

template< typename T >
struct identity
{
    typedef T type;
};

// ----------
// Function signature metafunction implementation
// Also handler for function object case
// ----------

template< typename T >
struct function_signature_impl
    : function_signature_impl< decltype( &T::operator() ) >
{
};

// ----------
// Function signature specializations
// ----------

template< typename R >
struct function_signature_impl< R () >
    : identity< R () >
{
};

template< typename R, typename A1 >
struct function_signature_impl< R ( A1 ) >
    : identity< R ( A1 ) >
{
};

template< typename R, typename A1, typename A2 >
struct function_signature_impl< R ( A1, A2 ) >
    : identity< R ( A1, A2 ) >
{
};

// ----------
// Function pointer specializations
// ----------

template< typename R >
struct function_signature_impl< R ( * )() >
    : function_signature_impl< R () >
{
};

template< typename R, typename A1 >
struct function_signature_impl< R ( * )( A1 ) >
    : function_signature_impl< R ( A1 ) >
{
};

// ----------
// Member function pointer specializations
// ----------

template< typename C, typename R >
struct function_signature_impl< R ( C::* )() >
    : function_signature_impl< R () >
{
};

template< typename C, typename R, typename A1 >
struct function_signature_impl< R ( C::* )( A1 ) >
    : function_signature_impl< R ( A1 ) >
{
};

template< typename C, typename R >
struct function_signature_impl< R ( C::* )() const >
    : function_signature_impl< R () >
{
};

template< typename C, typename R, typename A1 >
struct function_signature_impl< R ( C::* )( A1 ) const >
    : function_signature_impl< R ( A1 ) >
{
};


// ----------
// Function signature metafunction
// ----------

template< typename T >
struct function_signature
    : function_signature_impl< T >
{
};


// ----------
// Tests
// ----------

template< typename F >
void test( F f )
{
    typedef function_signature< F >::type signature_type;

    std::cout << typeid( F ).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << '\t' << typeid( signature_type ).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


int foo( int )
{
    return 0;
}

struct bar
{
    int operator ()( int )
    {
        return 0;
    }

};

struct cbar
{
    int operator ()( int ) const
    {
        return 0;
    }

};

struct abar1
{
    int operator ()( int ) const
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int operator ()( int )
    {
        return 0;
    }

};

struct abar2
{
    int operator ()( int )
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int operator ()( double )
    {
        return 0;
    }

};

struct mem
{
    int f( int ) const
    {
        return 0;
    }
};


int main()
{
    test(
        []( int ) -> int { return 0; }
    );

    test(
        foo
    );

    test(
        &foo
    );

    test(
        bar()
    );

    test(
        cbar()
    );

    test(
        std::function< int ( int ) >( &foo )
    );

    test(
        boost::function< void ( int ) >( &foo )
    );

    /*
    test(
        std::bind( &mem::f, mem(), std::placeholders::_1 )
    );
    */

    /*
    test(
        boost::bind( &mem::f, mem(), _1 )
    );
    */

    /*
    test(
        abar1()
    );
    */

    /*
    test(
        abar2()
    );
    */

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

(No code for checking agains inproper arguments was added.)

The idea is that `function_signature< decltype( f ) >::type` should be the signature of a call of `f( ... )` where that "..." is the signature. This means in particular that pointer to member function is an invalid argument here (although the code does not check against this) since such pointer cannot be "called" directly.

At the end are tests which fail (in VS 2010). All due to `operator ()` being overloaded. And this makes that code mostly useless as it will not work with the result of `bind`. But maybe it can be further developed.

---

Answer to André Bergner's query:

`function_signature_impl` never derives from itself. It is a type template which only means a loosely coupled family of actual types. But the actual types (even thou they belong to the same family) are distinct types.

The `&T::operator()` is a pointer to a call operator (`operator()`) of type `T` – obviously. Basically just a member function pointer (where the member function happens to be a call operator). While `decltype` of it is the type of that pointer. This might seem insignificant (especially that `type_info::name` of both shows the same) but for templates it does matter since one is a pointer while the other is a type (apparently).

This “case” is needed to cover for functors (types which objects are “callable”). Note that this unspecialized `function_signature_impl` is used only if the template argument `T` doesn’t match anything else among the listed “cases”.

I hope I got it right after that long time. Although I’m not sure if I ever truly and fully understood it. The code was a bit result of experimenting.

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem and like your solution. Could you please comment on that weird definition of `function_signature_impl` which derives from itself: `function_signature_impl<decltype(&T::operator())>`. How is this possible? And why do I need this for detecting `operator()` ?

Answer (score 1):

This answer was just given to me by SlashLife on freenode ##c++:

```
template <typename T, typename Signature>
struct signature_impl;

template <typename T, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct signature_impl<T, ReturnType(T::*)(Args...)>
{
    using type = ReturnType(Args...);
};

template <typename T>
using signature_t = signature_impl<T, decltype(&T::operator())>;
```

The caveats are that it only works if there is a unique `operator()` and it doesn't work for lambdas.

Comment: It doesn't work for any `operator()` that is cv-qualified, which applies to lambda as they are always implicitely const. You'll need to supply a specialization for `const` (and if want to be truly pedantic, also for `volatile`, `const volatile`, and also any of those permutations with `&` and `&&`)

Comment: You could also make use of the fact that something like `A T::*` will automatically deduce `A` to any function signature, although that would keep on the cv and ref qualifiers. It's a shame the type traits manipulators don't work on function types.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::is_invocable_r`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable)

Comment: This C++17 feature wasn't available 11 years ago when I asked this. ;) But thanks for adding this since someone might get here now when this is already a feasible option.